# Magento 2: Product listing page event

Tags: product, event-observer, price, category-listing

So I want to update the price of a  specific products in product listing page programatically.
To update, I created product attribute and I would like to take that value and update the price in an observer.
Which product listing page event should I use to achieve this?
If there is any alternative to update the price I am open to suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below event

```
catalog_block_product_list_collection
```

You need to allow your new attribute to use in product list to get value for that attribute.